# What type of product can I use to tint exterior primer?

Tags: concrete, exterior, primer

What product can I mix to add a bit of color to this [KILZ2 water-based primer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/KILZ-2-ALL-PURPOSE-5-Gal-White-Interior-Exterior-Multi-Surface-Primer-Sealer-and-Stain-Blocker-20000/100116594)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tint your primer yourself, you an use a univeral colorant.   One brand is called Mixol, you can find it online or at a specialty store like Rockler wood working.

I recommend you review the Kills2 TDS for specifications regarding tinting.
https://www.kilz.com/binaries/content/assets/kilz/pdf/msds/2000-tds_us.pdf
Says 2oz of tint per 128oz of paint.   I know in older TDS they said tinting could interere with stainblocking.  If you want to stainblock, I recommend you  spot test first.

Also, you may just try going to a big box store.  Take the paint in and just ask them to tint it for you.  I've had them shake up cans and even add tint to paint that they don't even carry.  I was usually purchasing something else at the time, so they did not mind.  Just go when they are not busy.

Answer (score 1):

Almost anyplace that sells paints starts with something in the white to black range and then tints it as needed, using concentrated mineral pigments (which resist fading under UV). If you buy a can of primer and ask them to tint it for you, I'm sure they'd be glad to do so for a minimal cost.

If you want to tint it yourself, concentrated mineral pigments might be your best bet since they resist fading and are compatible with just about every variety of paint. Craft or woodworking suppliers may stock these.

Comment: Thanks. I'm asking because I won't be buying it at a hardware store.

Comment: The same wholesaler that's getting you the paint probably has colorants -- Mixol, Trans-Tint, etc. You want one that uses the same solvent that your finish is dissolved in, or that is a dry powder so solvent isn't an issue. For larger quantities, a mixing paddle that you can chuck in a power drill may be a very good investment.

Answer (score 1):

I would not bother tinting primer - it is not designed as a color coat but a substrate to support one or two coats of top coat.